# Disable Left-Super from window tiling

Tags: gnome, keyboard

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and currently left and right SUPER plus arrow keys both trigger window snapping - I want to set this so ONLY right super performs any window mgmt, is this possible?

Poking around it seems that UG 15.10 uses mutter as the window manager - which is responsible for the window tiling. Look at the xml setting definitions and the Keyboard app I can see the settings for `Windows -> View Split on Left|Right` which is set to `Ctrl+Alt+Left|Right`, however on my machine in addition to this customisable shortcut also `Super+Left|Right` triggers it, which is driving me mad coming from a mac - where this jumps to the end of line.

I may be able to get around this by swapping CTRL & Super but every time I try to do this with xmodmap some applications dont register the change or disable super completely!

Thanks for any help

EDIT

`wm`

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward ['<Shift><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Primary><Alt>KP_0']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-7 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-8 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-9 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-left ['<Super><Shift>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-5 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-6 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-center @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize ['<Primary><Super>Down', '<Super>Down', '<Alt>F5']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu ['<Super>s', '<Alt>F1']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows ['<Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-run-dialog ['<Alt>F2']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Primary>Page_Down', '<Control><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-ne ['<Primary><Alt>KP_Prior']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e ['<Primary><Alt>KP_Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings always-on-top @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Super><Shift>Page_Up', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize ['<Primary><Super>Up', '<Super>Up', '<Primary><Alt>KP_5']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-group-backward ['<Shift><Alt>F6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-n ['<Primary><Alt>KP_Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-s ['<Primary><Alt>KP_Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-horizontally @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w ['<Primary><Alt>KP_Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-nw ['<Primary><Alt>KP_Home']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move ['<Alt>F7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-down ['<Super><Shift>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-se ['<Primary><Alt>KP_Next']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings activate-window-menu ['<Alt>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source ['<Super>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-above @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-right ['<Super><Shift>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward ['<Shift><Super>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-last ['<Super><Shift>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings lower @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels ['<Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-fullscreen @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-on-all-workspaces @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-up ['<Super><Shift>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-sw ['<Primary><Alt>KP_End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded ['<Primary><Alt>s']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 ['<Super>Home']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise-or-lower @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels ['<Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward ['<Shift><Super>Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-vertically @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['<Primary><Super>d', '<Primary><Alt>d', '<Super>d']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications ['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized ['<Primary><Alt>KP_5']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings set-spew-mark @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-resize ['<Alt>F8']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-last ['<Super>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group-backward ['<Shift><Super>Above_Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group ['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-group ['<Alt>F6']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close ['<Alt>F4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Primary>Page_Up', '<Control><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-1 ['<Super><Shift>Home']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-2 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-3 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-4 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right @as []
```

Getters

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right
['<Primary><Alt>Right', '<Super>Right']
$ gsettings get org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left 
['<Primary><Alt>Left', '<Super>Left']
```

mutter before sets

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.mutter.keybindings        
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right ['<Super>Right']
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left ['<Super>Left']
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings tab-popup-cancel @as []
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings tab-popup-select @as []
```

mutter after sets

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.mutter.keybindings                         
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right ['<Super_R>Right']
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left ['<Super_R>Left']
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings tab-popup-cancel @as []
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings tab-popup-select @as []
```

So after the above all looks fine - but In fact If I go into the `keyboard` tool it now look like...

[image]

And as you can see now the arrows left and right will trigger the split (which is of course not ideal!)

Comment: Press: Ctrl+Alt+F1 to go to a console. In there, log in under an admin user, and type `showkey --scancodes` If you press the left and right super keys  and get different values when you press them, yes this is possible. (please leave a note with the codes below here)

Comment: Left super 0xe0 0x5b 0xe0 0xdb 
Right super 0xe0 0x5c 0xe0 0xdc

Comment: Have edited but that cmd is not complete?

Comment: Sorry!  `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`

Comment: Have edited the above with the output - will comment on answer

Comment: Ah! You've got an answer already!  Good! Enjoy the new experience!

Comment: Not exactly! Read to the end!

Comment: OK.  So would you consider using  [Ctrl-Shift-Alt ] left and right to do this then???

Comment: That was just a random pref I applied when messing around - I think I will however just settle on the same as OSX Spectacle tiling and use CTRL+ALT+Arrows. Cant seem to enable R Super only - must be poss as the os does it for viewing gnome shell using R super only! Prob best to do the same as osx in this case for muscle mem anyhow. Will upvote your comments :)

Comment: Please drop by in chat so we can discuss this and ping me @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW

Comment: Hey, what 'chat' are you referring too? Thx

Comment: [Click here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Answer (score 4):

This **should** do

get current settings

`gsettings get org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right`

`gsettings get org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left`

set Super_R

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right "['<Super_R>Right']"`

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left "['<Super_R>Left']"`

Comment: Have updated the Q - this has an undesirable side effect!

Comment: Appreciate the question answer but a bit annoying you auto got half the bounty as it did not solve the issue!